# Java Threading: Unexpected behavior when providing timeout argument in lock.wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex

Unfortunately I'm not going to be able to give full context to this, since there's too much complexity in the surrounding code. The short of it is this:

I have a block of code that's waiting on a lock:

```
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.wait();
            }
```

Which works as expected. Fairly straightforward -- it acquires the lock, releases it when it starts waiting, another thread acquires the lock and then notifies on it.

However, as soon as I provide a timeout, the behavior changes entirely.

```
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.wait(60000L);
            }
```

Again, should be fairly straightforward (and this works as expected in several other places in the code). However, in this one case, execution basically halts until the timeout occurs. My only guess as to what seems to be happening is it's not releasing the lock when it enters the wait -- the notifier is never able to acquire the lock, so the wait sleeps until it times out. And even worse, it's a blocking sleep -- no other threads are able to wait on the lock and it forces the execution to be entirely synchronous.

Anyone have any ideas as to what might be happening here? It's a fairly simple function and there's nothing weird going on with nested synchronization blocks at any point. Considering that by providing no timeout it should wait indefinitely, if the notifier itself was broken the code would be hanging forever, but that's not the case. It only stops working once the timeout is provided.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

OS: OS X 10.8.5

JDK: 1.6.0, 1.7.0.45 and 1.7.0.67

Comment: Your best bet for us to help you is to give a simple test that illustrates what youre seeing.

Comment: To address your misconceptions -  If a thread invokes `lock.wait(60000l)` it will sleep for 1 minute but also give up the lock so it wouldn't be a blocking sleep as you are worried about.

Comment: Where's the `notify()` call?  Chances are, you are experiencing a lost notification.  `notify()` does not do _anything_ if there is no other thread that is already blocked in a `wait()` when notify is called.

Comment: If you are using this block of code inside a while loop (as you should), move the synchronized block out, and wrap the while loop, not just the waiting part. Lock acquire and release incur a significant overhead, and it is recommended to hold the lock for the duration of the loop.

Comment: @JohnVint Believe me, I wish I could. This works as expected elsewhere and it's only occurring in this one instance. I am aware that it SHOULD be giving up the lock when providing a timeout (and in all cases except this one it certainly does). Only in this case does it appear to not be giving up the lock and I'm at a loss as to why.

Comment: @jameslarge An entirely different section of code. I'm very confident that the notifies are working as expected, since when providing no timeout, the code works as expected. If no notifications were happening, then the code would hang there. It only starts hanging once the timeout is provided, which is why this is so strange.

Comment: Yes, but my point is, you haven't showed it to us.  Until you show us a _complete_ example (e.g., how the wait() happens _and_ how the notify() happens), then we can only guess at what is wrong.

Comment: @jameslarge I'm aware, and it's not feasible. No simple example is able to replicate the issue. I know I'm basically asking for blind diagnosis and might not get anything useful, but I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: @Apropos Have you dumped a thread dump when it halts?  That may be helpful for us (and yourself if you haven't yet).

Comment: @JohnVint I have not done so. Good idea, I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Apropos If your notifying thread can't enter the synchronized block, some other thread is still synchronizing on the same lock object. That would explain, why your waiting thread never awakes and why it seems the waiting thread is still helding the lock. You should provide a thread dump and you should listen to the advice to call `wait` within a conditional loop! Calling `wait` without condition is useless. And please use `notifyAll` instead of `notify`!

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not show a while() loop around the wait() call.  That suggests that you may not completely understand the use case for wait and notify.  Here's one example:

```
// This object is used to synchronize *EVERY* method
// that can change the value of count.
final Object lock = new Object();

int count;

void waiter() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        while(count <= 0) {
            lock.wait();
        }
        //do something that you are only allowed to do
        //when count > 0.
    }
}

void notifier() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        count++;
        if (count >= 0) {
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

[Edit: Added this paragraph, thank's Nathan Hughes for reminding me that...] The wait() call is in a loop because the wait()ing thread still has to re-acquire the lock after the lock has been notified:  if thread A is waiting for the condition to become true, and thread B makes the condition true and calls notify(); there's no guarantee that thread C won't get the lock first, and make the condition false again before the wait() call is able to return.

Also, wait() is allowed to return even when the object has not been notified (that's called a "spurious wakeup").

The condition-to-be-waited-for is explicit in the code (i.e., count > 0).

Nothing changes the condition-to-be-waited-for except when synchronized on the same lock object that is used for wait() and notify() calls.

Comment: Without trying to go into an architectural discussion, let's assume for the moment I don't even care if it wakes up early. The issue is that it's NOT waking up at all. The notifications never occur -- as far as I can tell, the thread doing the notify can't acquire the lock, even though it should be released when calling wait().

Comment: @Apropos There are ways to mis-use wait() and notify() that lead to a type of bug called "lost notification."  Without seeing more of your code, I can only guess that that might be your problem.  If you are not wait()ing for an explicit condition, and you are not locking *EVERY* piece of code that can change the condition, then your program may be vulnerable to lost notification.

Comment: If it helps, I've thrown in logging and I can tell that the notifiers are never even able to enter the synchronization block (appear to be unable to acquire the lock). I wish I could provide you more code. It is not waiting for an explicit condition (so could be prone to a lost notification), but that doesn't appear to be what's happening in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of whether you provide a timeout or not the wait method on an object releases the lock held on the object by the current thread as commented by John.

With the code that you have given and based on your description of scenario my guess is that the moment lock.wait(60000L) is executed JVM releases the lock on the object meanwhile any other thread which is in runnable/running state might be picked up and if they are synchronizing on the same object then they might take the lock before your notifier thread would take the lock.

This behaviour is difficult to debug as it depends on JVM profiler to pick which thread should be run. So as you explained just when your lock.wait(60000L) is executed it need not always be that the notifier thread alone should pick up the lock on the common object . If there is any other thread which is also waiting on the common object it can very well get the lock finally leading to notifier thread not being able to get the lock and hence the lock.wait(60000L) gets timedout.

Comment: It's certainly not only the notifier thread that may be acquiring the lock (there are other threads which may also be acquiring the lock to wait), but if there was an issue (even intermittent) with the ability for the notifier to acquire the lock, I would certainly be seeing it when providing no timeout -- however, that's not the case. The notifier threads are able to acquire the lock as expected until I add the timeout. It consistently works with no timeout and consistently fails with the timeout.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you use **lock.wait(..)** you have to use the **lock.notify()** or **lock.notifyAll()**. Make sure you use that where it makes sense in your logic and it will 'wake up' the lock *before* the timeout (considering the timeout value you put is enough). Here it's some guide for its usage, i hope its useful: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/wait_notify_how_to.shtml

Comment: I'm sorry. Did you read my post? I'm aware of how it's supposed to be working. Like I said, it works as expected when not providing a timeout. Another thread notifies on the lock and the code continues executing as it should. When providing a timeout, the notifications no longer are happening because it appears the other threads are, for some reason, unable to acquire the lock. I further mention how it works as expected elsewhere in the code. Edit: For further clarification, if notify wasn't being called, the code would lock up with no timeout provided since it would wait indefinitely.

Comment: the wait doesn't 'keep' the lock, while it's waiting it allows other threads to acquire the lock, that's why of course that the notify() can be called. Check which other part of your code is written within the synchronized(lock)..some where else it might be keeping the lock, not on the 'wait()'.

Comment: just a little side note..'not keeping the lock' is the major difference from wait() and Thread.sleep(). This last one does hold the lock until it times out behaving like you described. (i.e. no body else can go inside that lock while it's sleeping).

Comment: Yes, I know. wait() is supposed to give up the lock. I was just saying that it was acting as if it were a blocking sleep instead of a wait. My only explanation for the behavior is that it's not, even though it should be. If it's really not, then somehow I've triggered a JVM bug (which seems unlikely). I could be entirely wrong as to what's actually happening, but I have no other explanations as to why merely providing the timeout causes the notifications to stop.

Comment: @AlécioCarvalho, no.  The _major_ difference between Object.wait(n) and Thread.sleep(n), is that if other programmers try to understand your code, they'll think that Thread.sleep(n) means it's delaying for some specific amount of time, and they'll think that foobar.wait(n) means it's waiting for some other thread to _do_ something.